# Threejs create skybox scene

Tags: javascript, webgl, three.js

I tried to create a skybox in three.js.

I created 2 scenes. The first is the skybox, and the second is my game scene.
I'm just learning three.js, and I don't really know, why it doesn't work. Only the skybox is rendered, the other scene isn't.

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/5bqFr/

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What's happening now is that, even if the skybox is being rendered first, you're also writing on the depth buffer. The skybox happens to be closer to the camera than the sphere and that's why you don't see the sphere.

You just need to disable writing into depth:

```
new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x0000FF, depthWrite: false } );
```

Comment: Thank you master! I'm not sure if it's the best way to create sky, but  it works, and that is the most important.